# APK upload on play store through gmail alert

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded apk on google play console using one of my gmail account, But i that day i got notification that "We noticed a new sign-in to your Google Account on a Linux device." But i didn't logged from Linux device ,its from windows.

**I want to know is this login related to google play console or google could platform.**

As we don't use Linux system on our office space. So i want to know how can i get to the result from which system this account is logged in.